# how do you pick certain fields in json format in php

Tags: php

I calling a url which returns the data as json format. I like pick out some variables from this output. The ouput is as follows:

```
{
  "graph_property" : [ {
    "name" : "calculation_method",
    "value" : "Geo Mean"
  }, {
    "name" : "graph_type",
    "value" : "TIME"
  } ],
  "measurement" : [ {
    "id" : "1132282",
    "alias" : "example.com"
    "bucket_data" : [ {
      "name" : "2013-JUN-20 11:23 AM",
      "id" : 1,
      "perf_data" : {
        "value" : "4.878",
        "unit" : "seconds"
      },
      "avail_data" : {
        "value" : "100.00",
        "unit" : "percent"
      },
      "data_count" : {
        "value" : "1",
        "unit" : "#"
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "2013-JUN-20 11:28 AM",
      "id" : 2,
      "perf_data" : {
        "value" : "-",
        "unit" : "seconds"
      },
      "avail_data" : {
        "value" : "-",
        "unit" : "percent"
      },
      "data_count" : {
        "value" : "-",
        "unit" : "#"
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "2013-JUN-20 11:33 AM",
      "id" : 3,
      "perf_data" : {
        "value" : "-",
        "unit" : "seconds"
      },
      "avail_data" : {
        "value" : "-",
        "unit" : "percent"
      },
      "data_count" : {
        "value" : "-",
        "unit" : "#"
      }
    } ],
    "graph_option" : [ {
      "name" : "perfwarning",
      "value" : "-",
      "unit" : "seconds"
    }, {
      "name" : "perfcritical",
      "value" : "-",
      "unit" : "seconds"
    }, {
      "name" : "availwarning",
      "value" : "-",
      "unit" : "percent"
    }, {
      "name" : "availcritical",
      "value" : "-",
      "unit" : "percent"
    }, {
      "name" : "bucketsize",
      "value" : "300",
      "unit" : "seconds"
    }, {
      "name" : "rows",
      "value" : "3",
      "unit" : "#"
    }, {
      "name" : "pagecomponent",
      "value" : "User Time",
      "unit" : "seconds"
    }, {
      "name" : "avg_perf",
      "value" : "4.878",
      "unit" : "seconds"
    }, {
      "name" : "avg_avail",
      "value" : "100.00",
      "unit" : "percent"
    }, {
      "name" : "total_datapoint_count",
      "value" : "1",
      "unit" : "#"
    }, {
    } ]
  } ],
  "link" : {
    "type" : "application/json",
    "href" : "http://api.keynote.com/",
    "rel" : "slotmetadata"
  }
}
```

The values I am interested are these:

```
 "

name" : "2013-JUN-20 11:23 AM",
     "value" : "4.878",

     "name" : "2013-JUN-20 11:28 AM",
     "value" : "-",

    "name" : "2013-JUN-20 11:33 AM",
     "value" : "-",
```

The reason I am doing it this way is that sometimes, the web service call returns emtpy values. From this output, I like to pick the latest date that does not have an empty value and then print out the name and value which is not empty.

Is there an easy way to pick the name and value field from this json output?

when I do

```
$data<-json_decode($resp)
print_r($data)
```

one portion of the data is this:

```
[measurement] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1132282
                [alias] =>example.com
                [bucket_data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => 2013-JUN-20 01:23 PM
                                [id] => 1
                                [perf_data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 3.074
                                        [unit] => seconds
                                    )

                                [avail_data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 100.00
                                        [unit] => percent
                                    )

                                [data_count] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 1
                                        [unit] => #
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => 2013-JUN-20 01:28 PM
                                [id] => 2
                                [perf_data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 3.416
                                        [unit] => seconds
                                    )

                                [avail_data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 100.00
                                        [unit] => percent
                                    )

                                [data_count] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 1
                                        [unit] => #
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => 2013-JUN-20 01:33 PM
                                [id] => 3
                                [perf_data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => -
                                        [unit] => seconds
                                    )

                                [avail_data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => -
                                        [unit] => percent
                                    )

                                [data_count] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => -
                                        [unit] => #
                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: did you try json_decode()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use built-in [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function

```
$data = json_decode('your_json_here'); //$data will be "stdClass" object
$data = json_decode('your_json_here', true); //$data will be "array" object
```

then you can operate with $data as with regular array/object

if type = stdClass:

```
$data->measurement[0]->bucket_data[0]->name; // will be equal "2013-JUN-20 11:23 AM"
```

if type = array

```
$data['measurement'][0]['bucket_data'][0]['name']; // will be equal "2013-JUN-20 11:23 AM"
```

Comment: there are bunch of nested arrays, how do you pick them?

Comment: $data['measurement']['bucket_data']['name'] will equal "2013-JUN-20 11:23 AM" and so on

Comment: when I do your suggestion, I get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: see my updated first answer for details

Comment: first of, thank you for helping me here. I get these eror: for stdObject: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object, for array: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bucket_data

Comment: i don't know what your script returns. Just look at your JSON object as on Array object, same nodes, same data. And try to get what you need, good luck! Try updated code in first answer